# Make a static variable injectable

Tags: java, dependency-injection

i am building a http API client that needs to call out to a specific endpoint like so:

```
public class MyApiClient {
    private static final String ENDPOINT ="http://myapi....";

}
```

Here the endpoint won't change so its constant. However, I want to be able to override this for testing so that I can test against a mock http server for example.

Whats the best way to do this? Is it just to make it an instance variable and provide it with a starting value:

```
private String endpoint = ="http://myapi....";

public void setEndpoint(String endpoint){
   ...
}
```

Comment: If `String ENDPOINT` must be static, then assign its value from the result of a `static` method, where this method reads the proper value from a configuration file or another datasource. This is one of the problems when working with WSDL and JAX-WS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are of course many solutions to this and one way of doing it is to use a system property with a default value:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_ENDPOINT = "http://myapi....";
private static final String ENDPOINT = 
        System.getProperty("my.endpoint", DEFAULT_ENDPOINT);
```

This way you get a configurable way of solving your problem. If you need even more flexibility when initializing your static constants you could also use a *static initializer*:

```
private static final String ENDPOINT;
static {
    // do initialization here but do not throw any exceptions (bad practice)
    // you can e.g. read from files etc...

    // Then assign your constant...
    ENDPOINT = 
}
```

System properties are passed on the command line as `-D` parameters e.g:

```
java -Dmy.endpoint=http://...
```

---

But in my opinion, **an even better approach** is to **actually inject** the value to the class that is using it:

```
public class ClassThatIsUsingTheConfig {
    private final String endpoint;
    public ClassThatIsUsingTheConfig(final String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // use endpoint
    }
}
```

And then, make the selection of which endpoint to use in the caller class. From a test case, this will be very easy to mock.

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        ClassThatIsUsingTheConfig var = new ClassThatIsUsingTheConfig(TEST_ENDPOINT);
        var.someMethod();
    }
}

public class MyProdClass {
    public void prodMethod() {
        ClassThatIsUsingTheConfig var = new ClassThatIsUsingTheConfig(PROD_ENDPOINT);
        var.someMethod();
    }
}
```

You can read more about [dependency injection here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

---

On a side note, if you are using some kind of framework for managing dependencies such as [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) or [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html) it is common to be able to inject properties and constants in various ways (e.g. based on which environment that is currently running). An example, when using Spring Framework you can declare all your constants in a property file and inject the property using annotations:

```
@Autowired
public ClassWhoIsUsingTheConfig(@Value("my.endoint") final String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
}
```

The property file for prod could be along the lines of:

```
my.endpoint=http://prodserver...
```

wheras the property file for test would look like this:

```
my.endpoint=http://testserver...
```

The approach of using a Dependency Injection engine allows for a very flexible way of handling external constants, paths, resources etc and simplifies your life when it comes to testing the code.